# Is there a standard macro to detect architectures requiring aligned memory access?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, memory-alignment

Assuming something like:

```
void mask_bytes(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src, unsigned char* mask, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int i;
  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
     dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
}
```

I can go faster on a non-aligned access machine (e.g. x86) by writing something like:

```
void mask_bytes(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src, unsigned char* mask, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int wordlen = len >> 2;
  for(i=0; i<wordlen; i++)
  {
    ((uint32_t*)dest)[i] = ((uint32_t*)src)[i] & ((uint32_t*)mask)[i]; // this raises SIGBUS on SPARC and other archs that require aligned access.
  }
  for(i=wordlen<<2; i<len; i++){
    dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
}
```

However it needs to build on several architectures so I would like to do something like:

```
void mask_bytes(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src, unsigned char* mask, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int wordlen = len >> 2;

#if defined(__ALIGNED2__) || defined(__ALIGNED4__) || defined(__ALIGNED8__)
  // go slow
  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
     dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
#else
  // go fast
  for(i=0; i<wordlen; i++)
  {
    // the following line will raise SIGBUS on SPARC and other archs that require aligned access.
    ((uint32_t*)dest)[i] = ((uint32_t*)src)[i] & ((uint32_t*)mask)[i]; 
  }
  for(i=wordlen<<2; i<len; i++){
    dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
#endif
}
```

But I cannot find any good information on compiler defined macros (like my hypothetical `__ALIGNED4__` above) that specify alignment or any clever ways of using the pre-processor to determine target architecture alignment. I could just test `defined (__SVR4) && defined (__sun)`, but I would prefer something that will Just Work<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup> on other architectures requiring aligned memory accesses.

Comment: The CPU makes the extra cycles to get the unaligned data and shift it into the right place. Normally this would significant slower then aligned getting. You should always try to read aligned...

Comment: Just like to say that I always worked on systems that cannot do cross aligned copies so that I've just come to assume the existence of normal and "fast" copies as normal.

Comment: Unfortunately this is in a library and I cannot control how the users of this library align the buffers they send me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While x86 silently fixes up unaligned accesses, this is hardly optimal for performance. It is usually best to assume a certain alignment and perform fixups yourself:

```
unsigned int const alignment = 8;   /* or 16, or sizeof(long) */

void memcpy(char *dst, char const *src, unsigned int size) {
    if((((intptr_t)dst) % alignment) != (((intptr_t)src) % alignment)) {
        /* no common alignment, copy as bytes or shift around */
    } else {
        if(((intptr_t)dst) % alignment) {
            /* copy bytes at the beginning */
        }
        /* copy words in the middle */
        if(((intptr_t)dst + size) % alignment) {
            /* copy bytes at the end */
        }
    }
}
```

Also, take a look at SIMD instructions.

Comment: Based on OP's defining `i` outside the `for` loop, I'm worried he doesn't have C99 or `intptr_t`.

Comment: Even without C99, every unix-like system I've seen has had `intptr_t` in `inttypes.h` for ages... I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: And +1 to Simon for solving the problem optimally even on archs that "allow" unaligned access. But it's probably a bad idea to make `alignment` a variable and not a constant.

Comment: +1, but I'd use `uintptr_t`, modulo of signed values is suspicious

Comment: and for the SIMD instructions, a good compiler should figure that out by himself, e.g if you'd give `-march=native` to gcc it would do that, I think, as soon as you give him large enough integer types to process.

Comment: I am concerned that copying both source buffers into aligned buffers, creating an aligned dest buffer, doing the mask in an aligned way, and then moving the aligned dest buffer back into the unaligned dest buffer that the user passed in will cost significantly more than just paying the cost for the unaligned bytewise mask in the first place.

Comment: I was using `memcpy` mainly as an example, because it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach would be to have a `configure` script that runs a program to test for alignment issues. If the test program doesn't crash, the configure script defines a macro in a generated config header that allows for the faster implementation. The safer implementation is the default.

```
void mask_bytes(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src, unsigned char* mask, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int wordlen = len >> 2;

#if defined(UNALIGNED)
  // go fast
  for(i=0; i<wordlen; i++)
  {
    // the following line will raise SIGBUS on SPARC and other archs that require aligned access.
    ((uint32_t*)dest)[i] = ((uint32_t*)src)[i] & ((uint32_t*)mask)[i]; 
  }
  for(i=wordlen<<2; i<len; i++){
    dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
#else
  // go slow
  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
     dest[i] = src[i] & mask[i];
  }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(I find it weird that you have `src` and `mask` when really these commute. I renamed `mask_bytes` to `memand`. But anyways...)

Another options is to use different functions that take advantage of types in C. For instance:

```
void memand_bytes(char *dest, char *src1, char *src2, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        dest[i] = src1[i] & src2[i];
}

void memand_ints(int *dest, int *src1, int *src2, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        dest[i] = src1[i] & src2[i];
}
```

This way you let the programmer decide.